# React Native ERROR: expected string or class/function": ParallaxScrollView

Tags: react-native

Hello I got stuck at this parallax scrollview. I got the basic code from this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-parallax-scrollview). I don't why but I am getting this error [the image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8AJB.png).
This is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

import ParallaxScrollView from 'react-native-parallax-scrollview';

const SCREEN_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get('window').height;

export default class Aboutme extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <ParallaxScrollView
        windowHeight={SCREEN_HEIGHT * 0.4}
        backgroundSource='http://i.imgur.com/UyjQBkJ.png'
        navBarTitle='John Oliver'
        userName='John Oliver'
        userTitle='Comedian'
        userImage='http://i.imgur.com/RQ1iLOs.jpg'
        leftIcon={{name: 'rocket', color: 'rgba(131, 175, 41, 1)', size: 30, type: 'font-awesome'}}
        rightIcon={{name: 'user', color: 'rgba(193, 193, 193, 1)', size: 30, type: 'font-awesome'}}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Can someone help me how to solve this please.
EDIT: 
Now I found error that its not recognizing is thie below line.

```
import ParallaxScrollView from 'react-native-parallax-scrollview';
```

and the error is

```
`Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-native-parallax-scrollview'. 'd:/Deepthi/REACTNATIVEWORKSPACETWO/DesignOne/node_modules/react-native-parallax-scrollview/src/ParallaxScrollView.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.Try `npm install @types/react-native-parallax-scrollview` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-native-parallax-scrollview';``
```

so I have installed

`npm i @types/react-native-parallax-scrollview`.

and got new error

`@types/react-native-parallax-scrollview@latest' is not in the npm registry.`

please help me

Comment: Try adding this element into `<View></View>` main container element.

Comment: did !! failed too

Comment: Remove leftIcon and rightIcon for testing, as I think you have to install font-awesome plugin and then import here in your file. or just add any static image object in leftIcon and rightIcon and run the project

Comment: @KirankumarDafda I have removed everything  and did its not working. see the edit once

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine, did you install the packages(`npm i`) and restart the metro bundler(node process) after adding the packge?